# Can I apply CSS rules of one HTML5 element to another HTML5 element without editing core files and duplicating rules?

Tags: html, css

Can I apply CSS rules of one HTML5 element to another HTML5 element without editing core files and duplicating rules? If I can then how should I do that?

This is the simplified version of the problem I have:

The content of `core.style.css`:

```
abbr {
    color: #ff8c00;
}
span {
    color: #e9967a;
}
```

The content of `extension1.style.css`:

```
abbr {
    /* applying style rules of span of core.style.css */
    color: #e9967a; 
}
```

As you see, I would like `abbr` of `extension1.style.css` to have the same rules as `span` of `core.style.css` has. If somebody updates `span` of `the core.style.css` then `abbr` of `extension1.style.css` should also update.

**Edit:**
JavaScript is not an option.

Comment: Why do you have the same definition in 2 different files? Sounds like you need a `common.style.css` file.

Comment: Short answer: no. Question: Is JavaScript an option?

Comment: Is your ultimate goal to have the style in extension1.style.css be the dominant one and override the style in core.style.css? If so, ``!important`` can be your friend.

Comment: @omri-aharon   The definition of abbr is not the same in core.style.css and extension1.style.css.

Comment: @david-z-lerner !important does not solve the problem. Both definitions of abbr are equally important.

Comment: if you get really stuck and there isn't that much to add on you could copy the css that you want and put it at the bottom of the css that you want to overide, the rule will cascade down. Only a thought and onlt if there isn't much to overide.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in plain CSS. You should look into CSS preprocessors like [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) or [Less](http://lesscss.org/) to use variable-like stuff in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of copying the new style, why wouldn't you have `core.style.css` to have the core css:

```
abbr {
    color: #e9967a;
}
span {
    color: #e9967a;
}
```

and the `extension1.style.css` have the styles to overwrite the core where you'd want to:

```
abbr {
    color: #ff8c00;
}
```

Then just load the CSS on the pages where you want a different color on `abbr` after loading the core CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="style/css" href="core.style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="style/css" href="extension1.style.css" />
```

---

Alternatively there is a method where you could work with PHP and in your case any kind of data holder.

**HTML:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="style/css" href="core.style.php" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="style/css" href="extension1.style.php" />
```

**CSS:** `core.style.php`

```
<?php 
header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
$color = // color variable obtained from data holder
?>

span {
    color: <?=$color;?>;
}

abbr {
    color: #e9967a;
}
```

**CSS:** `extension1.style.php`

```
<?php 
header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
$color = // color variable obtained from data holder
?>

abbr {
    color: <?=$color;?>;
}
```

Comment: You are basically about duplicating rules. What if somebody changes the span of core.style.css? The abbr of extension1.style.css will not change then... My point is to change rules of abbr of extension1.style.css if the rules of span of core.style.css is changed.

Comment: Okay now I am wondering: Why would you want `abbr` in `extension1.style.css` to overwrite `core.style.css` to a style that could be just set in `core.style.css`, then overwritten in `extension1.style.css` if needed on that page? I think that what you want is not what CSS is designed for, and I think you should just have a core and overwrite styles in `extension1.style.css` where you would like to.

Comment: Note that with your PHP solution you are essentially creating your own preprocessor. Not a totally bad idea if it's for a one-off requirement, but in the long run it's probably easier to avoid reinventing the wheel and use one of existing CSS preprocessors. (Plus it'll probably help out with a bunch of other CSS pains you have!)

Comment: @daan-heskes   At first, I do not want to change the core of the system (core.style.css is part of the core). Secondly, the part of abbr styling the same as span is needed for my own extension only, not for others. I can make the change and copy->paste core rules into my own module, but if somebody would make any change in core.style.css then I would have to make the same change in extension1.style.css over and over again...

Comment: @jarek-piórkowski The solution with PHP code (or any other server side code) would do the job, but this kind of change requires editing the core. I do not want to edit the core. However, I see that I have no options to choose from, because plain CSS will not solve the problem...